# Mongoose save() method not writing to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

So I'm updating an attribute of a user sub document in mongoose, but it's not saving to my database.

Here's my function:

```
@User.findOne({'email': email}, (err, user) ->
    if err?
        callback(err)
    else if user?
        for account in user['accounts']
            if account['account_uuid'] is account_uuid

                account.state = "Verified"

                user.save((err, updated_user, numberTouched) ->
                    if err?
                        console.log err
                        return callback(err)
                    else
                        console.log 'Successfully verified account'
                        console.log updated_user

                        return callback(null, 'Successfully verified account')
                )
                return                        
        callback(new Error('No account for account_uuid'))
)
```

The really frustrating thing is that `updated_user` returns with the `account.state` attribute being "Verified" and the `numberTouched` variable returns as 1, meaning 1 document has been affected by the save. But when I check the user document in my DB, it's still the default value of "Pending".

Any thoughts?

P.S. I'm using a development database with MongoLab. But I don't think the problem is with them since I can update other attributes just fine.

Comment: Does your sub schema have an id attribute?

Comment: Ah, no actually. Adding one fixed it!

Comment: I can't handle mongoose silent fails...

Comment: Can you update your question to include your schema definition?

Comment: I once fixed a similar issue using Mongoose's `.markModified()` function. Does it fix the issue in this case too?

Comment: you might want to add an answer with explanation of what you had to do to fix it since someone else with similar problem might find this question.

Comment: My other favorite silent Mongoose failure: The database has not been connected to, and no error is through when querying it without a connection.

Comment: @ConnorBlack will you please post you fix to your question and mark it answered :)

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it, this question should not be in the "unanswered" tab anymore, 8 month after you did found how to fix it...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are changing a mixed-type subdocument, you will need to call `user.markModified('accounts')` to let Mongoose know what's changed before you save.

However, if two of these operations happen concurrently, you could be losing data. I would recommend you use the `findAndModify` command, in conjunction with `$elemMatch` and `$set` operators.

Answer (score -1):

In the line you're putting

```
for account in user['accounts']
```

you're creating a new variable, independent of the User model instance. You could use that variable to show the data (for example through a REST API) but not for modify the User model instance. aka. You are modifying another variable.

Instead, try to modify the user you're getting from the findOne() query and save it.